# What does XCode installing do when solving 'gem install sqilte3' error(Failed to build gem native extension.)?

Tags: ruby, xcode, sqlite

I was trying to install gem sqlite3 but failed with error below.
**ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:

    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151016-8328-1i1buur.rb extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-dir /usr/bin**

 extconf.rb failed 

**Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.**
.....
I just searched through and solved it via installing XCode before installing sqlite3, can anyone tell me the reason? What does XCode actually do?
I am a newbie on those gem of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Installing XCode (or more precisely the XCode command line tools) will also install the toolchain needed to compile the native extensions (written in C) needed by the sqlite3 gem.